# android list view with text image and button, using the SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

I only have a ListView containing TextView. I would like to add an image and a button to each row in the list, such that when i click on the button, it will send the data gotten from SimpleCursorAdapter and bring me to another activity.

I have got two xml files. one that contains the ListView and the other xml file contains the TextView, ImageView and Button.

I have read many articles in stackoverflow and online, but i still cant get it working. I think there is something which is got to do with the getView(), onClickListener for the button but i do not know how to link it together with the SimpleCursorAapter class. As in my case, i did not extend SimpleCursorAdapter but used it directly. I am confused about how to allow it to access the xml file which contains the button and image. my current code is like this:

```
public class BoardsActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_SUBSCRIBE = 0;
private AnnouncementDbAdapter dbAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;
private Button subscribeButton;
//private LayoutInflater mInflater;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subscribe_to);
    // mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    dbAdapter = new AnnouncementDbAdapter(this);
    //      dbAdapter.open();
    //      fillData();


@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
dbAdapter.open();
fillData();

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
dbAdapter.close();

private void fillData() {
cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllBoards();
startManagingCursor(cursor);

String[] from = new String[] {AnnouncementDbHelper.BNAME };
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.subscribeactivity_bname};

SimpleCursorAdapter board = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.subscribe_to_row, cursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(board);

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
Cursor details = dbAdapter.fetchBoard(id);
startManagingCursor(details);

Intent i = new Intent(this, BoardDetailsActivity.class);
i.putExtra(AnnouncementDbHelper.BID, id);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SUBSCRIBE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
dbAdapter.open();
fillData();}
```

How can i get the image from Drawables and when the user clicks on the button, it goes to another activity?

Comment: Try that link?? Lemme know if you find any difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to create Custom List view that will displays Textview,ImageView and button.

Check this for [Custom list view](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/)

Also check this [List View and Adapters available](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply! I tried but I still cant find a way to combine the usage of ListView (with textview, imageview and button) together with SimpleCursorAdapter class. Any idea how I could use these two together?